# Can I personalize the items of my mapview?

Tags: android, google-maps

i have a mapview with itemizedoverlay, like in the example of mapview in androids developers guide

i have my own icon on the items, but also i want to personalize them, adding some text, not only the icon. But i mean text visible on the map, not when i press on the item

can i do it? how?

Comment: Did you try searching StackOverflow for possible answers?

Comment: yes i did, and i dont find anything about text below the item image

Answer (score 1, accepted):

on this overrided ondraw  method (subclassing the ItemizedOverlay) i draw the icon bitmap and above the bitmap i draw a round rect with a text (item text), but with the canvas you can do anything you want.

```
if(!shadow){
            for (OverlayItem item : items) {
                Point point = new Point();
                proj.toPixels(item.getPoint(), point);
                TextPaint tPaint = new TextPaint();
                tPaint.setColor(Color.BLACK);
                tPaint.setStrokeWidth(20);
                Paint paint = new Paint();
                paint.setColor(Color.YELLOW);
                float measure = tPaint.measureText( item.getTitle() );
                float hMeasure = measure /2;
                RectF rf = new RectF(point.x-hMeasure, point.y-40, point.x+hMeasure, point.y-20 );
                canvas.drawRoundRect(rf, 5, 5, paint);
                canvas.drawText(item.getTitle(), point.x-hMeasure, point.y-25, tPaint);
                draw.setBounds(point.x-hWidth,point.y-hHeight,point.x+hWidth,point.y+hHeight);
                draw.draw(canvas);
            }
        }
```

cheers

Comment: what¿? can you explain me a little more how to do it? maybe with some code example? i can't find examples on google

Comment: i forgott to paste my code sample, this ondraw method is from a ItemizedOverlay subclass.